# Proof of convergence with central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to solve some problems and this one showed up: Show that
$$
e^{-n} \left(1 + n + \frac{n^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{n^n}{n!}\right) \to \frac{1}{2}
$$
as $n \to \infty$. The problem sugests to apply the Central Limit Theorem to a sequence of random variables with Poisson distribution. Can somebody help me with this? I don't know how to apply it correctly. And if someone knows some another way to prove this, I'll apreciate!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121099/limit-using-poisson-distribution

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that it was a duplicate (at least I did not found it).

Comment: I wonder if it is not the most duplicated question...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000437/lim-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-k-0n-fracnkk-frac12-basic-m