# the limit of Poisson CDF with diverging rate parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, poisson-distribution, rate-of-convergence

The CDF of a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$ is
$$
P(n;\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}.
$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, the CDF would certainly approach 1.

Now, consider the case when the rate parameter is $\xi n$ with $\xi\in(0,1)$ being a given constant.
According to the last answer in [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk), the following limit should be 1:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n;\xi n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n\xi)^ke^{-n\xi}}{k!}=1.
$$
Is it possible to check the convergence rate of the above limit?
More specifically, I wonder whether the convergence rate is faster than $n$, i.e., whether $n[1-P(n;\xi n)]=O(1)$?

I checked using software that the convergence rate is faster than $n$, but I don't know how to show it rigorously. Can anyone provide some hints and insights? Thanks!

Comment: $\lambda$ is the mean, and you are asking the limit of the probability of being at the mean or below.  The median is close to the mean, so $\frac12$ would be a natural guess for the limit

Comment: Empirically for large $n$ it seems something like $\frac12 + \frac{0.266}{\sqrt{n}}$, confirmed in the answers an comments to the linked question

Comment: Let $X_n\sim \text{Poisson}(n)$. If $n$ is large then $X_n$ is approximately normal with mean $n$ and variance $n$.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000437/321264.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k\,e^{-n}}{k!}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n)}{\Gamma (n+1)} \to \frac 12$$